# "message": "Cannot read property 'query' of undefined",

Tags: node.js, express, graphql, prisma, prisma-graphql

My environment is currently graphql-yoga with prisma.  When attempting to run queries I am faced with "Cannot read property 'query' of undefined" error.  I am assuming this is because it cannot read it from the context

This issue came about when I was refactoring the code and setting up the Prisma connection.  I have included prisma in the context when starting the server, but it does not seem to be available anywhere.

error

```
[nodemon] starting `babel-node src/index.js`
The server is up!
TypeError: Cannot read property 'query' of undefined
    at Object.query (G:\laragon\www\engine-backend\src\resolvers/Query.js:23:23)
    at G:\laragon\www\engine-backend\node_modules\graphql-tools\src\schemaGenerator.ts:695:54
    at next (G:\laragon\www\engine-backend\src\directives/directives.js:21:12)
    at field.resolve (G:\laragon\www\engine-backend\node_modules\graphql-tools\src\schemaGenerator.ts:692:18)
    at resolveFieldValueOrError (G:\laragon\www\engine-backend\node_modules\graphql\execution\execute.js:467:18)
    at resolveField (G:\laragon\www\engine-backend\node_modules\graphql\execution\execute.js:434:16)
    at executeFields (G:\laragon\www\engine-backend\node_modules\graphql\execution\execute.js:275:18)
    at executeOperation (G:\laragon\www\engine-backend\node_modules\graphql\execution\execute.js:219:122)
    at executeImpl (G:\laragon\www\engine-backend\node_modules\graphql\execution\execute.js:104:14)
    at Object.execute (G:\laragon\www\engine-backend\node_modules\graphql\execution\execute.js:64:63)
```

I have tried googling and searching around but it seems that I cannot find any answer.

Here is the code

```
// index.js
const { GraphQLServer } = require("graphql-yoga")
require('dotenv').config()
const { checkJwt } = require("./middleware/jwt")
const { getUser } = require("./middleware/getUser")
const { importSchema } = require("graphql-import")
const { makeExecutableSchema } = require("graphql-tools")
const { directiveResolvers } = require("./directives/directives")
import { resolvers } from './resolvers/index'
import { prisma } from './prisma/prisma'


const schema = makeExecutableSchema({
  typeDefs: importSchema("./src/schema.graphql"),
  resolvers,
  directiveResolvers
})



const server = new GraphQLServer({
  schema,
  context: req => ({
    ...req,
    prisma
  })
})

server.express.post(
  server.options.endpoint,
  checkJwt,
  (err, req, res, next) => {
    if (err) return res.status(401).send(err.message)
    next()
  }
)
server.express.post(server.options.endpoint, (req, res, next) =>
  getUser(req, res, next, prisma)
)

server.start({ port: process.env.PORT || 3000 }, () => {
  console.log('The server is up!')
})
```

```
//prisma/prisma.js
import { Prisma } from 'prisma-binding'
require('dotenv').config()
import { fragmentReplacements } from '../resolvers/index'

const prisma = new Prisma({
//   fragmentReplacements: extractFragmentReplacements(resolvers),
  typeDefs: "src/generated/prisma.graphql",
  endpoint: process.env.PRISMA_ENDPOINT,
  secret: process.env.PRISMA_SECRET,
//   debug: true,
  fragmentReplacements
})

export { prisma as default }
```

```
// resolvers/Query.js
const Query = {
    users (parent, args, { prisma }, info ) {
      prisma.query.users(null, info)
    },
    async leadPhones (parent, args, { prisma }, info) {
      return prisma.query.leadPhones(null, info)
    },

}
export { Query as default}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are exporting the Prisma instance as the default export:

```
export { prisma as default }
```

so you should import it as a default

```
import prisma from './prisma/prisma'
```

Importing it as a named export is causing the resulting variable to equal `undefined`. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export) for the difference between named and default exports.

Comment: Thank you, that did remove that error.  Now it seems its throwing an error that has rather strange formatting - https://paste.pics/d102aa54281cafec33fb4521bfd3d598

Comment: Okay it was an error in my .env with the Prisma url.   Everything is working as intended.  I appreciate the help